# Select statement not returning all values

Tags: mysql

This function works fine, what is flipping me out is that the array returned has all the information needed except $row[15] which has data in it on the table Orders

```
function SelectOrder($orderid)
{
    connect();
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Orders` WHERE `OrderID` =".$orderid." LIMIT 0 , 30");
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    return $row;
}

print_r($row);
```

Prints

```
Array ( [0] => 24 
[1] => Grei 
[2] => Tristram 
[3] => 19 2nd Blvd. 
[4] => Richmond 
[5] => J7V 5R6 
[6] => Ontario 
[7] => Canada 
[8] => grei@email.ca 
[9] => (514) 555-5555 
[10] => Snow Removal 
[11] => 210 
[12] => 32.5 
[13] => 23.07 
[14] => 200.57 
[15] => 
[16] => 123 same street 
[17] => 1 
[18] => 0 )
```

When I use the same select statement within PHPMyAdmin

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM `Orders` 
 WHERE `OrderID` = 24 
 LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I get value [15] (SNAME = Frank Ditripani)

PHPMyAdmin SQL Results

```
OrderID-Fname-Lname-Address-City-Pcode-Prov-Country-Email-Phone-Service-Price-Discount-Tax PYMNTAmount-SNAME-SADD-Agreed-PayPalPaid
24-Grei-Tristram-19 2nd Blvd.-Richmond-J7V 5R6-Ontario-Canada-grei@email.ca-(514) 555-5555-Snow Removal-210-32.5-23.07-200.57-Frank Ditripani-123 same street-1-0
```

Both `SNAME` and `SADD` are the exact same properties in the table which is `varchar(50)` and `SADD` is returned but not `SNAME`.

This is the first time I have ever posted a question I usually find my answers here but this one is driving me nuts! and I am a bit embarrassed as the answer is probabley an easy one.

Comment: It makes me wander there is a special character that is causing it not to come through? like an accented letter or a '...

If you manually edit the row to contain something known, like "TEST" then does it work?

Comment: Special char in the name? Sure you're connecting to the same DB?

Answer (score 0):

The query might be the same, but is the database the same?

Check that you are connecting to the *same* database!

My bet is the connection parameters are different for the two programs.

Comment: Quick update I tried deleting the field in the table and re adding it giving it a text format in the same order.....still same problem..

Comment: Well the code all works just that glitch of displaying array[15] so what i did was add another field at the end of the table and called it SNAME2 varchar(50) and changed my script to append my form field to that instead, it worked! so in fact i cheated the problem now that its fixed i can proceed but it doesnt answer why this happened in the first place. after i finish the program i will re examine the original problem and update any findings.

Answer (score 0):

Check the connection character set - DB, client and connection should use the same one.

Comment: Update!......I deleted the field from the table and added it again giving it a text format in the same place in the table guess what! same problem.